# Overflow x and y on iPad device not showing

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css, overflow

I am having issues getting the scrollbar to show on a div on the iPad device.

I am using:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

This is working, however I want the scroll bar to be visible before the user actually touches the `div` to enable the scroll bar!

I only want the `overflow-y` to be visible on the iPad when you come into the page, then once the user touches the div only show the `overflow-y`!

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need JavaScript to change the style, or add/remove a class.

CSS

```
.match{
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
.match.post-scroll{
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
}
```

JS (using jQuery)

```
$(".match").one("click", function(){
    $(this).addClass("post-scroll");
});
```